# Is there a way of comparing two Lists with streaming?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class called `MyClass` that contains couple of members and one of them is `myString`:

```
public class MyClass{
  //...
  private String myString;
}
```

Now, I have a collection of `MyClass` and another collection of `String`.

My question is:

**How to compare those two collections with streaming? Is that possible?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by compare? Do you want to see if them both (all elements) are strictly equal?

Comment: Yes, I want to make sure they both have the same Strings. No more and no less.

Comment: My main question is how to pull out only one member of the class into a different collection.

Comment: I updated my answer with another example!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could map a list of `MyClass` to a List of Strings and then compare them normally:

```
List<String> anotherList = listOfMyClass.stream()
      .map(MyClass::getMyString)  //Assuming that you have a getter for myString
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could also join all the elements of the list in a single `String` and compare them directly. This will only work if the order of the elements should be the same in both lists. Examples below:

```
    final String joinSeparator = ", ";

    String firstResult = stringList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(joinSeparator));

    String secondResult = myClassList
            .stream()
            .map(MyClass::getMyString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(joinSeparator));

    //Just compare them using equals:
    System.out.println(firstResult.equals(secondResult));
```